# Why I get error objects are not valid as a React child (found: [object Promise]). in map function React with Spring Boot?

Tags: reactjs, spring-boot, axios

I've been dealing with this problem for 2 days. Even though I tried everything, I could not find the solution. I have two List. First list belongs to "applications". Second list belongs to "countries". Each country belongs to an application. Each application can have more than one country.
I want to list the number of countries for each application on React with the application information, but I am getting an error.

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from "react";
import {Link } from "react-router-dom";
import {getApps, deleteApp} from '../api/apiCalls'
import VisibilityIcon from '@material-ui/icons/Visibility';
import DeleteIcon from '@material-ui/icons/Delete';
import EditIcon from '@material-ui/icons/Edit';
import Switch from '@material-ui/core/Switch';
import {countLiveCountry} from '../api/apiCalls'

const ManagementList = (props) => {

const [apps, setApps] = useState([]);

  useEffect(() => {
    const fetchData = () => {
       getApps().then(response => 
        { setApps(response.data) 
         })
    };
    fetchData();
  }, []);

  const liveCountry = (id) => {
     let data = countLiveCountry(id).then((response) => response.data)
     return data
  }

  return (
      <div
        className="container"
        style={{ marginTop: 20, fontFamily: "tahoma" }}
      >
        <h2 style={{ float: "left" , font : 'bold'}}>Management</h2>
        <div style={{ float: "right" }}>


          <Link className="btn btn-danger btn-sm" to = "/management/newapp">Add New App</Link>
          <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger btn-sm ml-3">
            Plant Management
          </button>
        </div>

        <table className="text-center table table-sm table table-striped table table-bordered">
          <tr style={{ background: "#cccccc" }}>
            <th scope="col">Application Name</th>
            <th scope="col">Business Area</th>
            <th scope="col">Live Plants</th>
            <th scope="col">Line Stop Risk</th>
            <th scope="col">Actions<br></br><h7 className="col-2">View</h7><h7 className="col-2">Edit</h7><h7 className="col-2">Delete</h7><h7 className="col-2">Track</h7> </th>
          </tr>

          <tbody>
            {apps &&
              apps.map((app,id) => (
                
                <tr key={id}>
                  <td>{app.appFullName}</td>
                  <td>{app.businessArea.businessareaName}</td>

                  <td>{liveCountry(app.appID)}</td>
                  <td>Bu kısım sonra</td>
                  <td>
                    <Link
                      className = "btn btn-manage-link btn-sm col-2"
                      to={`/management/${app.appID}`}
                      
                    >
                      <VisibilityIcon></VisibilityIcon>
                    </Link>

                    <Link to={`/management/edit/${app.appID}`} className = "btn btn-manage-link btn-sm col-2"> 
                    
                    <EditIcon></EditIcon>
                    </Link>
                    <button onClick ={() => removeApp(app.appID)} className = "btn btn-manage-link btn-sm col-2"> 
                    
                    <DeleteIcon></DeleteIcon>
                    </button>
                   <Switch className="col-3"></Switch>
                  </td>
                </tr>
              ))}
          </tbody>
        </table>
      </div>

  );
};
export default ManagementList;
```

In Axios apiCalls.js

```
import http from "./http-common"
export const countLiveCountry = id => {
  return http.get(`/liveappcountry/${id}`)
}
```

In http-common.js

```
import axios from "axios";

export default axios.create({
  baseURL: "http://localhost:8080/api/1.0",
  headers: {
    "Content-type": "application/json"
  }
});
```

Country.java

```
package com.Manport.Backend.Domain;

import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonIgnore;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonProperty;
import com.sun.istack.NotNull;
import lombok.Data;


import javax.persistence.*;
import javax.validation.constraints.Size;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;


@Entity
@Data
@Table(name= "country")
public class Country  {

    @Id
    @Column(name="country_id")
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long countryId;

    @Column(name="country_tag")
    private String countryTag;

    @Column(name="country_name", nullable = false)
    private String countryName;

    @Column(name="country_fullname", nullable = false)
    private String countryFullName;

    @Column(name="country_shortcode", nullable = false)
    private String countryShortCode;

    @Column(name = "country_jdk",nullable = false)
    private String countryJDK;

    @Column(name = "country_jetty",nullable = false)
    private String countryJetty;

    @Column(name = "country_nodejs")
    @Size(max=12)
    private String countryNodejs;

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name="app_id")
    private Application app;

}
```

CountryController.java

```
    @GetMapping("/liveappcountry/{id}")
    Integer countLiveApp(@PathVariable Long id){
        int data = countryService.getLiveCountry(id);
        return data;
    }
```

CountryService.java

```
    @Override
    public int getLiveCountry(Long id) {
        return countryRepository.countLiveCountry(id);
    }
```

CountryRepository.java

```
public interface CountryRepository extends JpaRepository<Country,Long> {

    @Query(nativeQuery = true, value="select count(*) from country where country.app_id = :app_id ")
    int countLiveCountry(@Param("app_id") long id);
}
```

[In Postman return](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4KRRL.png)

[React error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zPJrE.png)

There is nothing I haven't tried for this. I tried the async function. But I couldn't get any results. If I delete **{liveCountry(app.appID)}** the application works fine but I need count. Please help. Thanks..

Comment: liveCountry is returning a promise, that's why you are seeing that error. I think you'd need to chain this request with the getApps

Comment: @erich Is there any subject or example that you suggest me to look for? Thx for help.

Comment: yea, take a look at this one, I hope it's helpful! https://codesandbox.io/s/vibrant-sea-h58ny

Comment: It really worked and you saved me another day, thx thx, i am grateful!! @erich